# A build only device cannot be used to run this target in Xcode8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode8

After installing Xcode8, i found the following issue while running build in device, i tried to set deployment target to 8.0 and clean my build to still facing the same issue and another side i have detach device and started xcode again facing same issue.

Any help would be appreciated...

Thanks

Comment: Did you resolve it?